# Infinite Abelian subgroup of infinite non Abelian group example

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

My thought is that we may take GL(2,F) as the group and this is obviously infinite and non abelian since matrix multiplication does not commute. Then I thought that if we make $\langle g\rangle$, for some $g$ in $\mathrm{GL}(2,F)$, which will be cyclic and hence Abelian, for instance:
$ g= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
1&0\\0&2 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$. Then $g^n$ will be in the form $ g^n= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
1&0\\0&2^n 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$. This is obviously infinite since $g^n=e \Leftrightarrow n = 0$.
Would this example work? Much thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A$ is an infinite abelian group and $H$ is a finite, non-abelian group then $A\times H$ works. [Also, you could take $F=\mathbb{Z}$ in your example to get something easy to work with, but which isn't a field :-) ]

Comment: A physical example: If you rotate a 3D object around the z-axis, those rotations are abelian. However, if you rotate it about both the z-axis and the x-axis, that's non-abelian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This example works indeed, if $F$ is infinite and $2^n\neq1$ in $F$ for all non-zero $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. This is satisfied for obvious candidates for $F$ such as $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$, but fails for other candidates such as the finite fields $\Bbb{F}_q$, but also infinite fields of positive characteristic such as $\Bbb{F}_p(T)$.

Assuming $F$ is a field, the condition that $2^n\neq1$ for all non-zero $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{char}F=0$, from which it follows that $F$ is infinite. So your example works if and only if $\operatorname{char}F=0$.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest example is $G=\mathbb Z \times S_3$ and $H=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: It's funny because the groups aren't simple.

Comment: **That's** math humor! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $\Bbb F$ has characteristic $0,$ that definitely works. Nicely done!

It also allows you to prove an inclusion $\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow GL(2,\Bbb F).$

Answer (score 1):

A simple example: let $G = S(\mathbb Z)$, the group of all permutations of the integers. Let $A$ be the subgroup generated by the transpositions $\{(n,n+1) |\, n \in \mathbb Z, n \, \rm{ even} \}$. Since the generating transpositions are all pairwise disjoint, they trivially commute with each other.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it works if you take $F$ to be an infinite field for example.

Although, as was pointed out by others even in this case you'll have to make some assumptions on $F$ to get your particular example working.

I guess it'd be more natural to consider the subset of all diagonal submatrices. It certainly is a subgroup as $\mathrm{diag}(x,y)^{-1} = \mathrm{diag}(x^{-1}, y^{-1})$.

This subgroup is isomorphic to $F^\times \oplus F^\times$, which is abelian and infinite if $F$ is.

Comment: It does not work for infinite fields such as $\Bbb{F}_p(T)$.

Comment: ah obviously yes.

Comment: Changed it @Servaes, I had forgotten that he asked for a particular example to work.